# Using Image multiple times

Tags: image

I think i've got a pretty simple problem, and i dont really understand why it actually IS a problem :(
I crate some Images, then i add them to a table.
This works fine, until i want to use one Image more than once, then the Program crashes.
(Telling me i have to call removeView() first, but i dont really want to do that, huh?)

Now the code, it choses a fitting image for a sertain measured value.
It always adds 4 images. Sometimes of corse the values are similar, then one image would be needed several times.

```
    ImageView imgGreen = new ImageView(this);
    ImageView imgYellow = new ImageView(this);        
    ImageView imgOrange = new ImageView(this);        
    ImageView imgRed = new ImageView(this);

    // allocate Images
    imgGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
    imgYellow.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);  
    imgOrange.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
    imgRed.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

    // add Images
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        switch(controller.array[1][i])
        {
            case 0: row.addView(imgGreen);  
                    break;
            case 1: row.addView(imgYellow);  
                    break;
            case 2: row.addView(imgOrange);   
                    break;
            case 3: row.addView(imgRed); 
                    break;      
            default: row.addView(imgRed);
                    break;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated :)
thanks in advance!

regards

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make a clone of the image resource and then add the clone the second time. Looks like it is expecting unique objects for each addView call.

Comment: You are right about the expectation of unique objects. Is there any way to change that? It would make things much more easy :)

Comment: I am guessing, it would try to change that, it could break things. Let's say you set image1's resource to imageResource1. On some particular event that occurs on image1 the properties of this imageResource1 might change. Now if this resource was changed, it would change the behavior for all the other unrelated images to which you might have added this resource as well. Which is a behavior you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, here the proper Solution :

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        switch(controller.array[1][i])
        {
        case 0:
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.green);
            break;
        case 1:
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            break;
        case 2:
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
            break;
        case 3:
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            break;
        default:
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            break;
        }
        row.addView(img);
    }
```

Its even less code now than before :)

regards